# How to benchmark SQL Server performance after hardware replacement?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

We are going to upgrade server with new hardware. And i'm kinda curious about how is SQL Server performance will improve. I'm not a DBA and know just a little about performance monitoring. My only idea is creating some heavy queries, run it before hardware replacement, run it after hardwaer replacement, compare execution time. Yeah i know that idea doen't even sounds good but it's all what i have.
Is there any way to benchmark performance in more common and efficient way?

Comment: enable query store

Answer (score 0):

Try to run a TPC-C benchmark with HammerDB

Answer (score 0):

[HammerDB](https://www.hammerdb.com/about.html) is the tool that you looking for, very easy to use, and you can make common tests or specific query tests with it. It is free and open source, you can download it from [here](https://www.hammerdb.com/download.html). Very easy to install and you can find very proper documentation for usage [here](https://www.hammerdb.com/document.html).

*NOTE: Don't forget to start and setup [agent](https://www.hammerdb.com/docs/ch07s01.html).*

If you are looking for something else too, I suggest the following [article](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-perform-a-performance-test-against-a-sql-server-instance/) on this topic.